# KML to shapes.txt conversion

Tags: kml, general-transit-feed-specification

i am trying to convert a kml file that i made on UMap website into shapes.txt using http://bdferris.github.io/kml-to-gtfs-shapes/
but it doesnt see anything in the map 
any special tools please ?

Comment: Is there any text output when you run the conversion tool? Does a shapes.txt get generated?

Comment: it generates a file including only the normal header of shapes.txt and no data

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I reproduced this behaviour with a simple KML generated using umap.

The tool (http://bdferris.github.io/kml-to-gtfs-shapes/) will only convert polylines, as it states in the first sentence of the website:

> This page provides a simple tool to generate a GTFS shapes.txt file
>   **from polyline entries** in a KML file.

(emphasis mine).

Polygons dont work and only produce the header line, polylines work and produce correct output.